# How to pass static navigationOptions with HOC in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, higher-order-components

I want to make an HOC to pass navigationOptions to the passed component.

```js
const withNavigationOptions = Component => ({ ...props }) => {
  const ComponentWithNavigation = Component;
  ComponentWithNavigation.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { title } = navigation.state.params;
    return {
      header: (
        <Navbar
          navigation={navigation}
          title={title}
          onBackPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}
        />
      )
    };
  };

  return <ComponentWithNavigation {...props} />;
};

export default withNavigationOptions;
```

But the static option is not being assigned to the returned component. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to pass navigationOptions to the rendered component is by passing it as props.

```
const withNavigationOptions = Component => ({ ...props }) => {
  const ComponentWithNavigation = Component;
  const navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { title } = navigation.state.params;
    return {
      header: (
        <Navbar
          navigation={navigation}
          title={title}
          onBackPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}
        />
      )
    };
  };

  return <ComponentWithNavigation {...props} navigationOptions={navigationOptions} />;
};

export default withNavigationOptions;
```

In your case the static option is not being supplied to the returned component since you are adding it on the rendered component and not the returned functional component.